# Why session.getAttribute returns null?

Tags: java, session, servlets, null

I've created a basic login and register page using servlets. My first servlet checks the database if the username and password exist and if they do it uses `session.setAttribute("user", username)` for second servlet. My second servlet has `request.getAttribute("user")` code. My project works just fine but in the second servlet returns `"Welcome null"` for output. How can I fix this? Thanks...

Sv1.java

```java
try {
    Connection Conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/?user=root");
    Statement s = Conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM users.info");
    while (rs.next()) {
        if (username.equals(rs.getString("Username")) && password.equals(rs.getString("Password"))) {
            session.setAttribute("user", username);
            flag = true;
            response.sendRedirect("./Sv2");
        }
    }

    if (flag == false) {
        out.print("Invalid username or password");
    }
}
```

Sv2.java

```java
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
if (session != null) {
    String name = (String) request.getAttribute("user");
    out.print("Welcome " + name);
}
```

Comment: In the example above you do not set the value for 'username'. So you probably put a null into the session.

Comment: ```String username = request.getParameter("username");``` I have this line in my Sv1.java actually... Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting it to the session

```
session.setAttribute("user", username);
```

& reading it from request

```
String name = (String)request.getAttribute("user");
```

Comment: Try `session.getAttribute("user");`